# Xamarin FacebookSDK not working correctly

Tags: facebook, xamarin

I'm trying to share something on Facebook with this piece of code:

```
ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(activity);

ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
.SetContentTitle("asdasdasdasd")
.SetContentDescription("asdasdasdasdasd")
.Build();

shareDialog.Show(content);
```

It opens the sharing dialog, but with an empty message.
Any ideas what's wrong ?

Comment: The message part of any share always has to be typed in by the user; your app is not allowed to pre-fill it in any form.

Comment: Ok that's true, but if i add .setContentUrl() it doens't work because it returns a  java.lang.Object instead of a ShareLinkContent.